# Android Bluetooth data transmission using Handler

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, inputstream

As a beginner in Android I have stupid problem. I do application that can receive data from Bluetooth measurement system. Data transmission works cool because I can display it in console in Android Studio, but I need to display it in one of my Activities in loop.

Part of code of method `run()` in Bluetooth class (I know that `input` is `String`, I have converted it to `int` before sending)

```
while (true) {
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                socket.getInputStream()));
        input = in.readLine();
        if (input.contains("+++")) {
            handler.obtainMessage(input).sendToTarget();
        }
    }
```

Code of handler in Activity:

```
Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message message) {
            textView.setText(message.what);
        }
};
```

After that application crashes with error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x6
```

Anyone has an idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x6

Due to :

```
textView.setText(message.what);
```

line.

As see [Message.what](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Message.html#what) return `int` type of value but `TextView.setText` require `CharSequence` type value.

When we pass `int` value to `TextView.setText` method, system treat int value as resource id and trying to find it when no resource is available with given int then it will through `NotFoundException: String resource ID`

Show `int` value as in TextView:

```
textView.setText(String.valueOf(message.what));
```

Comment: @Vades: good if it's working but important is if you get point why it's crashing :)

Comment: I know. I will remember it to use next time :)

Answer (score 0):

you can also try

```
textView.setText(message.what+"");
```